# How to set a default database for a Windows Authenticated user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I log in to a sql database with windows authentication, I want to set a specific database as the default database. I do not want the master to be the default.

I know you can do it for a sql user, but is it possible for a windows authenticated user? If so, how?

Comment: Same as for sql user. What would possibly be the difference?

Comment: This is what I have for the sql user, but it does not seem to work for the username of the windows user.  :   Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='login', @defdb='Database_Name'

Comment: Don't use the `sp_` procedures, use `ALTER LOGIN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most options for the [`ALTER LOGIN` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) are identical for SQL Authentication logins and Windows Authentication logins.

```
ALTER LOGIN [Domain\Username] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = database_name;
```

You can also do this through the UI, but it's more work IMHO, and you can't store keystrokes and mouse clicks in source control. In Object Explorer, expand your server, expand Security, expand Logins, right-click your login, select Properties. On the main screen at the bottom there is a `Default Database:` drop-down. Change it and click OK.